# springframework/remoting class not found

Tags: java, spring, web-services

I am trying to setup JAX-WS client using spring.  I have the below bean definition.  Getting the error below.

```
<bean id="someClient" class="org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean">
<property name="serviceInterface" value="somePortType" />
            <property name="wsdlDocumentUrl" value="file:///someWSDL.wsdl"/>
            <property name="namespaceUri" value="soemNS" />
            <property name="serviceName" value="Services201006" />
        </bean>
```

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean] for bean with name ‘someClient' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/jax-ws.xml]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/remoting/jaxws/JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean (Module "deployment.JbossEAP_WS_WebServiceEAR.ear.JBossEap_WS_SpringService.war:main" from Service Module Loader): Failed to link org/springframework/remoting/jaxws/JaxWsPortClientInterceptor (Module "deployment.JbossEAP_WS_WebServiceEAR.ear.JBossEap_WS_SpringService.war:main" from Service Module Loader): org/aopalliance/intercept/MethodInterceptor

Answer (score 1):

which version of spring are you using? It seems like a dependency is missing in the war file. The JaxWsPortClientInterceptor is part of spring-web.jar